# Spark Web UI - compressed data size

Tags: apache-spark

The input data is stored in a cloud storage in the form of multiple JSON files compressed in the .gz format. Based on some tests, it has been determined that the .gz compression format provides a compression ratio of at least 5-6 times when compared to the uncompressed data. The Spark job is responsible for reading this data, applying filters, parsing nested JSON fields, and then writing the processed data to a target location in the delta format.

Each day, the volume of compressed input data is approximately 1.3 terabytes, and the Spark job is configured to process data for one day at a time.

When examining the Spark web user interface, we can observe that there are two distinct jobs, one for reading and another for writing:

- The first job (job-1) has an input data size of around 1.3 terabytes.
- The second job (job-2) also reports an input size of approximately 1.3 terabytes and an output size of about 2.9 terabytes.

**Question**: Given the understanding that Spark should uncompress the data if the input is in a compressed format, it raises the question of why the Spark web UI is showing both jobs with an input size of approximately 1.3 terabytes when the uncompressed data would be expected to have a higher size.